# implement Zend_Controller_Router_Interface

Tags: zend-framework, zend-controller-router

Here I would like to have a tree of controllers different from that offered by Zend.
Let me explain, in many of my projects I find myself with controllers with over 1000 lines of code which is not very top side of code maintainability. So I want to cut my controllers, ie.

Example current controller:

```
UserController class extends Zend_Controller_Action {

listAction public function () {}

editAction public function () {}

.......

groupListAction public function () {}

groupEditAction public function () {}

.......

roleListAction public function () {}

roleEditAction public function () {}

.... etc.
}
```

So in this example I will like to outsource the concept of groups and roles in other controllers and other issues.

Desired architecture:

```
- controllers /
- UserController.php
- User /
--- GroupController.php
--- RoleController.php
```

->  url:

```
http://www.site.com/user/ -> class UserController
http://www.site.com/user_group/ -> class User_GroupController
http://www.site.com/user_role/ -> class User_RoleController
```

So I do not know how to apply this type of cutting.

If someone with an idea I'm interested.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom  controller dispatcher. Class must implements Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Interface, or you can extends Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard.

The easiest way is to extend Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard, because you will only need to override some of the parent methods.

```
class My_Dispatcher extends Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard
{
    public function isDispatchable(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
       // your code to find the correct class
    }

    public function loadClass($className)
    {
       // your code to load the correct class
       // return the correct class name (e.g. User_RoleController)
    }

    public function getActionMethod(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
       // your code to find the correct method name
    }
}
```

Set the new dispatcher class in your bootstrap:

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{

    public function _initMyFrontController()
    {
        $this->bootstrap('frontController');
        $frontController = $this->getResource('frontController');
        $frontController->setDispatcher(new My_Dispatcher());

        return $frontController;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your reply but i find the solution just by create custum routes.
ie.

```
routes.core_user_group_index.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static"
routes.core_user_group_index.route = "admin/core/user_group"
routes.core_user_group_index.defaults.module = "core"
routes.core_user_group_index.defaults.controller = "user_group"
routes.core_user_group_index.defaults.action = "index"
```